# Maximum Column in a Table of Presentation layer Oracle

Tags: oracle, presentation-layer

does anyone know what is the **maximum number** of columns that can be inserted in a presentation-layer in the Oracle administration tool?

Comment: Please describe the goal you want to achieve. Are you going to create 1 billion column presentation layer?

Comment: No no, I would like to bring about 500 columns into a table in the presentation layer. Is there a limit on the number of columns?

Comment: For an oracle DB, there's a limit of 1000 columns, but I have no idea what pres layer you're talking about.

Comment: I'm talking about the Administration Tool of Oracle, where you can work on RPD. There are 3 layers inside: physical, logical and presentation (it show you subject Area, tables, columns for reports, dashboard etc..)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is a limit number of columns I can put inside a table which is located in 'Presentation Layer' of Oracle BI Administration Tools?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/bi.1111/e10540/presentationlayer.htm#BIEMG266)? It would be helpful to include all the relevant information and clarification by editing your question.

Comment: Yes yes, exactly